# Implementation of SAML 2.0 using Angular and Node

Tags: node.js, angular, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I am a beginner to SAML SSO integration in Angular + Node project. I went through many of the links and forums realted to it. However, not able to figure out, From where to start???.

Still trying to find a way to implement the SAML SSO in my application.

Below is the scenario:

- I have an Angular application, in which I have implemented the login through Active Directory. Which is working fine.
- Now, once logged in, I come to the dashboard page.
- On this Dasboard page there is a link to a application.
- On click on this link I have to implement the Single Sign On using SAML.
- On successfully done the SSO. User will move to that application.

This is it!!!

I am done with the Active Directory login and come to the dashboard already. But now, I do not know, What to do, How to do, From where to start????

Got stuck here!!! Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you ask the community to recommend a library that does saml2 on node.js, remeber that such questions are rather not welcomed here and are subjects to be closed. On the other hand, if you already picked a particular implementation (google for "nodejs saml2") and you have specific issues, please come back with actual questions.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a client-side SAML stack e.g. [I need a SAML stack — now!](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

This then talks to a SAML identity provider.

Which IDP are you planning to use.

Comment: Sadly does not help with the question regarding Angular, but at least the author gets some clicks on his article!

Comment: Actually it does. The article has some JS possibilities etc.